# What happens if a company denies repair of a digital device under warranty?

Tags: contract-law, software, business, warranties

I hope I'm posting this on the right board.
I would just like to ask for advice on this issue of mine regarding a telecom company (PLDT).
So the thing is, My mother signed up for an internet plan with an included android tablet which is meant to be payed monthly for 3 years. After 8 months the device malfunctioned due to it being infected by a virus (adware mostly). The company refuses to fix the device since they claim to only acknowledge physical defects or damages, not software.

I can try to fix the tablet myself (voiding the warranty) but the firmware flash files have not been made public because the device is an obscure tablet from Huawei.

She is still going to be billed for 28 more months. Despite the fact that the device is unusable making the internet plan also useless.

My question is, what can we do about all this? (barring just paying the bill)

Comment: Outside of law: The tablet is not only obscure but probably the cheapest tablet they could find. The best thing you can do is probably to buy any decent tablet. You paid $X for 36 months of internet, and $x for the cheapest possible tablet. For a small investment you can get the use of your $X and at the same time get a better tablet. Your loss is $x, which is very likely a tiny amount of money.

Comment: Worst case scenario: nothing. Best case: there is a repeated pattern of this and a lawyer would be interested in taking the cases and getting it certified as a class action.